# Recursive Function: Is this recursive function correct to find if the number is a power of the base?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def sum_factor(num,base):
  
    while num>=base:
        if num==base:
            return "Yes"
    num=num/base
    sum_factor(num/base,base)
    return "Nope"

print(sum_factor(12,2))
```

Comment: Can you test it first - and share what you got?

Comment: Sorry the indent for return is wrong. It should have been aligned with while.

Comment: Try this visual platform with different input data - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: first you should test it on few examples. Maybe use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I already see that this code is wrong - inside `while` you don't change `num` so this loop will run forever. maybe you means `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: using `while` you can create code without recursion. And if you want recursion then inside function you have to use `return sum_factor(num/base,base)` to return result to previous execution.

Answer (score 0):

I already see that this code is wrong - inside `while` you don't change `num` so this loop will run forever. But using `while` you will create normal function without recursion. In recursion you rather need only `if/elif/else`.

And in recursion you have to use `retun sum_factor(num/base, base)` to return value to previous executed `sum_factor()` which will return it to previous executed `sum_factor()`, etc.

---

Something like this:

```
def sum_factor(num, base):
  
    if num == base:
        return "Yes"
    if num < base:
        return "Nope"
    
    #if num > base:
    #    return sum_factor(num/base, base)

    return sum_factor(num/base, base)

# --- main ---

print(12, 2, sum_factor(12, 2))
print(16, 2, sum_factor(16, 2))
print(9, 2, sum_factor(9, 2))
```